# App blocks: Invalid tag 'schema': unknown key 'blocks'

Tags: shopify, extention-cli

Validation errors                                                                                          bundle: [blocks/about01.liquid] Invalid tag 'schema': unknown key 'blocks',
[blocks/about01.liquid] Invalid tag 'schema': unknown key 'presets'

My app needs to have some blocks. What is a problem?

```
{% schema %}
{
   "name": "About 1",
   "settings": [
      {
         "type": "header",
         "content": "Content"
      },
      {
         "type": "richtext",
         "id": "title",
         "label": "Heading",
         "default": "<h2><b>Highlight the growth of your company by the numbers</b></h2>"
      }
   ],
   "blocks": [
      {
         "name": "Counter",
         "type": "counter",
         "settings": [
            {
               "type": "header",
               "content": "Content"
            },
            {
               "type": "text",
               "id": "card_number_before",
               "label": "Text before number"
            },
            {
               "type": "text",
               "id": "card_number",
               "label": "Number",
               "default": "2015"
            },
            {
               "type": "text",
               "id": "card_number_after",
               "label": "Text after number"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "presets": [
      {
         "name": "About 1",
         "blocks": [
            {
               "type": "counter"
            },
            {
               "type": "counter"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
{% endschema %}
```